# Simple way to delete a relationship by ID in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, nosql, cypher, graph-databases

Using **Match** and **Where** can delete a relationship by ID.

```
Match ()-[r]-() Where ID(r)=1 Delete r
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the old syntax, but that will be removed in a future version.

```
start r=rel(id) delete r;
```

Answer (score 29):

I use

```
MATCH ()-[r]-() WHERE id(r)=49 DELETE r
```

Answer (score 8):

You can delete by simple modified chyper for delete some Relations.

This is my code:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->() WHERE id(r)=43 OR id(r)=44 OR id(r)=45 DELETE r
```